# Rails: Paperclip multiple images upload error: No handler found for []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to implement multiple images upload using Paperclip gem. I can see two images files in the parameters but I am getting an error **no handler found for []**.

I'm getting an error here at @passengerride = Passengerride.new(passengerride_params):

```
def create
 @passengerride = Passengerride.new(passengerride_params)
 @passengerride.user = current_user
 if @passengerride.save
  flash[:success] = 'Ad was successfully posted.'
  redirect_to passengerride_path(@passengerride)
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

views/passengerride/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @passengerride, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
 <div class="form-group ">
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2 requiredFiel">
   <%= f.label :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <%= f.text_field :title, class: "select form-control", placeholder: "Eg: Bedroom" %>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group ">
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2 requiredFiel">
   <%= f.label :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
   <%= f.file_field :image, class: "select form-control", placeholder: "Eg: Bedroom", multiple: true %>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

passengerrides_controller.rb:

```
def passengerride_params
 params.require(:passengerride).permit(:title, { image: :preview })
end
```

passengerride.rb:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                url: "/system/:hash.:extension",
                hash_secret: "abc123"
validates_attachment :image,
                   styles: { original: ['500x500>', :jpg] },
                   content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
                   presence: true,
                   size: { in: 0..5000.kilobytes }
```

[Full Stack Trace](https://gist.github.com/sainath55/a2441b7fcac6d65925d6f7016e180f25) here.

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error? Can you please paste the error message with the line number and the whole stack trace into your question?

Comment: @spickermann I pasted the error message along with the stack trace.